# can't resolve another child project when running mvn tomcat:run

Tags: java, tomcat, maven-2

I'm developing a maven project with following structure:

```
main // project which packaging is pom  
|-- datalevel-project
|-- service-project 
`-- web-ui-project
```

I'm trying to run project on tomcat but when I command `mvn tomcat:run` on the folder of main project I get an error while it is building the service-project:

```
Failed to resolve artifact.
Missing:
1) datalevel-project:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

and so on..

I have set all child projects to main project with `module` tag and all child projects have parent and its `relativePath` to `../main` project.

Can somebody tell me where is the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, dependencies are resolved through your local repository. Did you `install` (in maven sense) the datalevel-project (and other artifacts) to your repository? I suggest to run `mvn install` on your main project to build and install everything first.

Secondly, why do you run `mvn tomcat:run` on the aggregator pom (the main project)? I'd expect this goal to be called on a project with a packaging of type `war` (the web-ui-project).

Thirdly, I have a doubt about the way you declared the `relativePath`. Given your project structure, it should be `../pom.xml` which is actually the **default** value so you could omit it (providing relevant pom snippets would help).

Comment: It was all about that installing project.. Thank you Pascal!!